# C unix sockets. Signals to handle

Tags: c, sockets, unix, signals

which kind of signal i've to handle in a AF_INET socket, both server and client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you're doing what you're doing, you *may* have to handle `SIG_PIPE`, which can happen when the connection is arbitrarily broken.

You should not have to handle any other signals.

If you are using `select()` or `poll()` or (personal preference) `epoll()` you should check for errors (eg, `POLLHUP`) *before* you check for read/write availability.

You should also always check the return value of `read()/write()/send()/recv()`.  If there's an error, they return -1, but if they return 0, that means the other end disconnected.  Ie, a read of 0 does just mean 0 bytes were read but the connection is still good.  It isn't.  Close the socket.  This is stipulated by POSIX.

Comment: i've asked this because in the first versions of my code, when a segmentation fault occurred on server, client goes to infinity loop...
so in that case, client received also a SIG_PIPE ?

Comment: @SvenMarnach i've already use timeouts on both side (just using alarm() function), but i would like to know if there are other kind signals to handle :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach: if you have to resort to timeouts or threads you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @giozh: no, SIG_PIPE does not cause a seg fault.

Comment: @goldilocks i don't say that SIG_PIPE cause segmentation fault! what happened to me was that server crashed for seg fault, and client gone in infinite loop! what i've asking is if when the server process (my server code menage all the connection on the client/server app) crash , client get back SIG_PIPE?

Comment: @giozh: Not necessarily, but it might. You should check the return value from `read()` or `write()` (or `send()/recv()`, which ever).  They'll return -1 on error.  Additionally (this is often not documented), **if they return 0**, that indicates the other end has disconnected (qv. POSIX specification) and you should `close()` the socket.  I'll edit that into the post ;)